# Check datetime inputted and datetime from database

Tags: sql, datetime

I need to check if the inputted schedule(datetime) of a room(Room1) is not in conflict with the schedule(the same schedule or not in range) of the room(Room1) that is already reserved. I have this query:

```
SELECT {Reserved}.[Id] FROM {Reserved}
WHERE ('2017-07-14 8:00:00' between {Reserved}.[FromDate] and {Reserved}.[ToDate] ) and
         ( '2017-07-19 12:00:00'between {Reserved}.[FromDate] and {Reserved}.[ToDate] )
```

Database sample data:

```
2017-07-14 8:00:00
2017-07-17 12:00:00
```

But the problem is it will not display anything. Thank you.

Comment: Tag DBMS, provide more sample data (what's in the table?)

Comment: @RahulKurup there's no reason not to use `between` in this case.

Comment: You have ANDed conditions and the 2nd is clearly outside of the range. Looks like you want to compare two ranges: `start_1 <= end_2 and end_1 >= start_2`

Comment: @JohnHC i have a table{reserved} with room id, Title,DateFrom(DateTime), DateTo(DateTime), statusId. Room1 Meeting 2017-07-14 8:00:00 2017-07-17 12:00:00 1

Comment: i have used 'between' and it checks the in-between plus the tails. but another thing that bothers me is, if the input is StartDate2017-07-13 13:00:00 and endDate 2017-07-22 15:00 should be accepted. but it does not. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to check if two ranges overlap, the logic is:

```
start_1 <= end_2 and end_1 >= start_2
```

Depending on you needs the `=` might not be needed/wanted.

This translates to

```
SELECT {Reserved}.[Id] 
FROM {Reserved}  
WHERE '2017-07-14 08:00:00' <= {Reserved}.[ToDate]
  AND '2017-07-19 12:00:00' >= {Reserved}.[FromDate]
```